# Search for a certain combination of strings in serial and read the following characters until another set character stops the search

Tags: serial

I have the following serial message that I'm receiving from an ESP32 running GRBL:

```
<Idle|MPos:158.500,0.000,0.000|FS:0,0|Pn:H|Ov:100,100,100|SD:0.21,/instruction.nc>
```

I want to check the value after `SD:` which in this case would be `0.21`.
It is a value that represents the percentage of a file being read, so values between 100.00 and 0.00 are being sent.

My guess is to look for the `SD:` in the string and then read all characters until the `,` but I can't really find a way to realize that.

I found the `startsWith()` and the `substring()`function that are able to look for a set of characters in a string, but it seems like they can only check a set amount of characters which in this case doesn't work as `0.00` is 4 characters and `100.00` is 6 characters.

Any help is much appreciated!!

Comment: I'd split the string on `|` then for each substring split it on `:`. You then have key/value pairs that are easy to compare and work with. Use a C string not a `String` object and `strtok_r` and `strcmp` to do the job with minimal memory outlay. I'll write a proper answer later, I'm on my phone at the moment.

Comment: @Majenko thanks for the super quick reply! I 'll give it a try as far as I can!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you should really be working with a C string (`char *`) instead of a `String` object, otherwise you will be massively fragmenting your heap with the string manipulations to come.

Once you have your data in a C string (char array) you can use `strtok_r` to split the string on the `|` character, then for each substring further split it on the `:`.  You need the `_r` variant of `strtok` to make it "re-entrant" so you can have two tokenizations at once nested.

For example (untested):

```cpp
char *data = "<Idle|MPos:158.500,0.000,0.000|FS:0,0|Pn:H|Ov:100,100,100|SD:0.21,/instruction.nc>";
char *pair; // Pointer to a K/V pair
char *pairptr = data; // Pointer for outer strtok

// Split the string on the first |
pair = strtok_r(data, "|", &pairptr);

// While we have a K/V pair
while (pair) {
    char *kvptr = pair;
    // Split the substring into two parts on the colon
    char *key = strtok_r(pair, ":", &kvptr);
    char *val = strtok_r(NULL, ":", &kvptr);
    if (val) { // If we split the data correctly:
        if (strcmp(key, "SD") == 0) { // If the key is "SD" then
            Serial.print("SD data: ");
            Serial.println(val);
        }
    }
    // Get the next string portion
    pair = strtok_r(NULL, "|", &pairptr);
}
```

Once you have your `val` you can further split that down on commas in the same way as it's been split on the colon.